# Hide/expand layout in vaadin

Tags: javascript, layout, show-hide, vaadin

There's StackExchange button with a dropdown layout on this site on the top-left side. If you click on it, it opens, if you click on somewhere else, it's hidden. 
Is it possible to create a similar composition in vaadin application given a button and layout?

Two conditions are:

1. Know the state of the layout(hidden or shown) from the code(that's why javascript is not appropriate).
2. Button should expand and hide the layout and the rest area on the click should only hide it(the same as here with the StackExchange button).

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Two posibilities :

Native Vaadin : [PopupView](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PopupView.html). Here's an [example of using it](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#PopupViewContents) in the Vaadin Sampler. No control over the placing of the popup, and showing the popup can't be controlled by anything other than the view itself.

Vaadin Addon : [Overlays](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#PopupViewContents) Allows you to overlay any component (e.g. a layout) relative to any other component, can can be controlled by a seaprate component (e.g. a button)

Comment: Turned out that PopupView is not very good for this purpose because on double click when the content doesn't hide the original button it throws an exception so the content should always hide the button. Overlays don't solve this problem also.

Comment: PopView itself doesn't throw an exception on double click outside. see http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#PopupViewClosing, and choose the second example; double clickout side => no exception.

Comment: There's a button "Default popup" there. If the popup content doesn't hide this button when it appears and I click on the button, exception is thrown. In the demo, popup content hides the button so I can't click on it again.